# searching list of objects by key and returning count

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB with a Node API and one route needs to return a summary count of each type in a collection.

I am not using the MongoDB Aggregate pipelines because the data I need has already been sent to the API for other summary statistics in the same route.

*Note*: I have put the `_id`'s below in single quotes for ease of use but they are `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`'s.

So, given that I have an array of mongo objects like this:

```
const allObs = [
  {
    _id: '60d5f37fd93fb82ebe84d920',
    type: '60d5f1d4cdc8942dc5b6b12e',
    otherFields: 'about 10 - removed for clarity'
  },
  {
    _id: '60d5f389d93fb82ebe84d926',
    type: '60d5f1d4cdc8942dc5b6b12e',
    otherFields: 'ditto'
  },
  {
    _id: '60d5f39bd93fb82ebe84d92c',
    type: '60d5f1e3cdc8942dc5b6b138',
    otherFields: 'foobarbarfoo'
  }
]
```

and I have a lookup table like this...

```
const lookupTable = [
  { _id: '60d5f1d4cdc8942dc5b6b12e', type: 'duck' },
  { _id: '60d5f1decdc8942dc5b6b133', type: 'goose' },
  { _id: '60d5f1e3cdc8942dc5b6b138', type: 'crane' },
  { _id: '60d5f1e9cdc8942dc5b6b13d', type: 'heron' }
]
```

How can I go about creating a summary table like this?

```
[
  { name: 'duck', data: [2] },
  { name: 'crane', data: [1] }
]
```

The resulting table structure is a bit odd (data with single value arrays) but we need this structure for Apex Charts.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the basic logic is doing a groupBy and match with lookup table. It would be easier to do with `lodash` or a helper library. But also without using JS it can be done pretty easily.

For a quick solution u can use this:

```js
//Group by type and then storing the count
const grouped = allObs.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.type] = p[c.type] || 0;
    p[c.type] += 1;
    return p;
}, {});

// putting that into a result array.
const result = lookupTable
    .filter(entry=>grouped[entry._id]) //filtering whatever is not there
    .map(entry => {
        return { name: entry.type, data: [grouped[entry._id]] }
    });
```

You can do it in single pass using a good old for loop.

Output:

```
[ { name: 'duck', data: [ 2 ] }, { name: 'crane', data: [ 1 ] } ]
```

Comment: thank you! lodash is fair game if you want to add an example.